# How can I get a NSArray to contain each date of current week?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate

currently I can get a week's begindate and enddate, but I'd like to get entire week's  date and put it into a Array.I use + 1 to calculate the date but it will return wrong result when there are cross month.

Here is my code:

```
-(NSArray *) getWorkWeekDays:(NSDate *)date {
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]        
    initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSArray *period = [self getWorkWeekPeriod:date];//This function will return the begin and  end date of week based on the "date" parameter. return 2 Object

    NSMutableArray *weekDays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSInteger unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit |    
    NSWeekdayCalendarUnit |
    NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *bgnComps = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:period[0]]
    int bgnDay = [bgnComps day];
    NSString *firstDay = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",bgnDay];

    [weekDays addObject:firstDay];
    for (int i = 1; i <= 6 ;i++) {
        [ bgnComps setDay :([ bgnComps day ]  +  1 )];
        int nextDay = [bgnComps day];
        NSString *day = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",nextDay];
        [weekDays addObject:day];
    }
    return weekDays;}
```

//in this scenario when I gave 2013/11/25 as begin date and I will got 
    2013/11/25
    2013/11/26
    2013/11/27
    2013/11/28
    2013/11/29
    2013/11/30
    2013/11/31 <--- this is very wrong result here....
    Any suggestions? thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code fills an array with `NSDate` objects with the start times of every day in the current week

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDate *beginningOfThisWeek;
NSDate *beginningOfNextWeek;

NSTimeInterval durationOfWeek;

[calendar rangeOfUnit:NSWeekCalendarUnit
            startDate:&beginningOfThisWeek
             interval:&durationOfWeek
              forDate:now];

beginningOfNextWeek = [beginningOfThisWeek dateByAddingTimeInterval:durationOfWeek];


NSDate *date = beginningOfThisWeek;
NSMutableArray *dateArray = [@[] mutableCopy];

while (![beginningOfNextWeek compare:date]  == NSOrderedSame) {
    [dateArray addObject:date];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:NSUIntegerMax fromDate:date];
    comps.day +=1;
    date = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];

}
```

The problem in your code arises from the fact that you use `NSStrings` to represent the dates and although you use `NSDateComponents` you don't convert them to a date object but directly to a string.

If you want to have the date represented by strings you should use a `NSDateFormatter`.

---

Or if you feel more comfortable with a for-loop:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *beginningOfThisWeek;
NSTimeInterval durationOfWeek;

[calendar rangeOfUnit:NSWeekCalendarUnit
            startDate:&beginningOfThisWeek
             interval:&durationOfWeek
              forDate:now];


NSMutableArray *dateArray = [@[] mutableCopy];
NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:NSUIntegerMax fromDate:beginningOfThisWeek];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
    [dateArray addObject:[calendar dateFromComponents:comps]];
    ++comps.day;
}
```

Comment: although it first looks to be easy doing calendar calculations correctly is hard. You should watch the WWDC 2011 video [«Performing Calendar Calculations»](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/#performing-calendar-calculations). And never use `60*60*24 (86400)`, one day your code will break.

Comment: Understood!! Thanks for kindly remind for the correctly way doing calendar or 60*60*24 (86400) will certainly be used!